# Collection data in f.association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a RoR app that I started in Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2, and Bootstrap 2 with simple_form.  I decided to move to Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0, and Bootstrap 3 before continuing.  Here's one migration issue that has me stumped.

In the Rails 3.2 version this works fine:

```
<%= f.association :services, collection: @account.company.services, as: :check_boxes, label_method: :description %>
```

In the Rails 4.0 world it gives me nothing in the collection data. In Rails 4.0 these all work:

```
<%= f.association :services, as: :check_boxes %>
<%= f.association :services, collection: Service.all, as: :check_boxes, label_method: :description %>
<%= f.association :services, collection: Service.where(id: 1), as: :check_boxes, label_method: :description %>
```

On the Rails console, `@account.company.services` returns `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#< ... >]>` while `Service.all` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation [#< ... >]>`

Does anyone know the proper format to get my selections into an `f.association` collection?

**EDIT:**

It's working now.  Part of my problem turned out to be using a 'company' record that had no joined 'services' (my bad).  I did relate it to other issues though, all stemming from CollectionProxy replacing the older array (or Relation) return object.  I was able to fix most of these by using .to_a on the collection.

Comment: Which version of SimpleForm are you using in Rails 4?

Comment: Maybe, the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081484/association-not-working