# Association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models:

**Department**

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :patients, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :waitingrooms, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**Waitingroom** with fields `patient_id:integer` and `department_id:integer`

```
class Waitingroom < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :patient
end
```

**Patient** with `department_id:integer`

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  has_many :waitingrooms
end
```

I save a waitingroom after a patient was in the waitingroom! So now i tried to retrieve the patients who where in the the waitingroom of the department:

```
  def index
    @waited = @current_department.waitingrooms.patients  
  end
```

Somehow it didnt worked it returned this error:

```
undefined method `patients' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Waitingroom:0x374c658>
```

But this worked: What did i wrong? Thanks!

```
  def index
    @waited = @current_department.waitingrooms  
  end
```

Comment: I question your associations... How does a waiting room belong to a single patient, while a patient has *many* waiting rooms? Are you chopping your people up and putting one piece of person per room?

Comment: Ok you are right! I missed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invoke an association on a collection. You need to invoke it on a specific record. If you want to get all the patients for a set of waiting rooms, you need to do this:

```
def index
  rooms = @current_department.waitingrooms
  @waited = rooms.map { |r| r.patients }
end
```

If you want a flat array, you could (as a naive first pass) use `rooms.map { |r| r.patients }.flatten.uniq`. A better attempt would just build a list of patient ids and fetch patients once:

```
@waited = Patient.where(id: rooms.pluck(:patient_id).uniq)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it works! I only have one more little question: Is the second suggestion faster? I mean with pluck? Or why should i use it? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, potentially **much** faster.